# xPath - number() and strings

Tags: string, xpath, numbers

How does the function `number()` convert a string into a number? I've found out that it converts it to the closest mathematical expression, but this is not a clear answer. What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number):

> a string that consists of optional whitespace followed by an optional minus sign followed by a Number followed by whitespace is converted to the IEEE 754 number that is nearest (according to the IEEE 754 round-to-nearest rule) to the mathematical value represented by the string; any other string is converted to NaN

Answer (score 1):

Phil Vallone has given the XPath 1.0 definition.

XPath 2.0 defines string-to-double conversion by reference to XML Schema 1.0, which defines it thus:

A literal in the ·lexical space· representing a decimal number d maps to the normalized value in the ·value space· of double that is closest to d; if d is exactly halfway between two such values then the even value is chosen. This is the best approximation of d ([Clinger, WD (1990)], [Gay, DM (1990)]), which is more accurate than the mapping required by [IEEE 754-1985].

XSD 1.1 however relaxes the rules:

Any ·lexical mapping· that maps the ·lexical space· just described onto the ·value space·, is a function, satisfies the requirements of [IEEE 754-2008], and correctly handles the mapping of the literals 'INF', 'NaN', etc., to the ·special values·, satisfies the conformance requirements of this specification... Since IEEE allows some variation in rounding of values, processors conforming to this specification may exhibit some variation in their ·lexical mappings·.